# Role permissions don't get assigned to table moved from public schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create new schemas and transfer the table in public schema to these schemas, but whenever I'm moving a table from the public schema to another schema, the user/role which has usage access on the new schema, as well as on its tables (including future tables), isn't able to access the newly moved table.

The table (in **public** schema):

```
CREATE TABLE atable(ID INT);
INSERT INTO atable VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO atable VALUES(2);
```

New user:

```
create user x_user with login password 'x_user';
```

New schema:

```
create schema dw;
```

Then I grant it all the access to the new schema and its tables:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA dw TO x_user;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA dw to x_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA dw TO x_user;
```

For tables added to the schema in the future

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA dw GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO x_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA dw GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO x_user;
```

Now I change the schema of the `atable` to **`dw`**:

```
ALTER TABLE atable SET SCHEMA dw;
```

Also, I create another table in the **`dw`** schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dw.btable(id int);
INSERT INTO dw.btable VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO dw.btable VALUES(4);
```

Now when I connect to the database, using the new user credentials, and run:

```
SELECT * FROM dw.atable;
```

I get: `ERROR: permission denied for relation atable 1 statement failed.`

Whereas if I run the same query for `btable` , which was created in the **`dw`** schema, it works.

```
SELECT * FROM dw.btable;
id
---
3
4
```

It also works when I move a table from one schema to another, but when I'm moving a table from the **public** schema to another schema, it is not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA` affects only the current contents of the schema.

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA` affects tables *created* in the schema.

Neither of these have any effect when moving tables from one schema to another, and I'm not aware of anything which does.

It should be possible to do this by creating an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html) which fires on any `ALTER TABLE` command and applies the appropriate `GRANT`. Unfortunately, while you can write these trigger functions in PL/pgSQL, I don't think it (currently) provides any way to find out what the actual command was; you'd need to either:

- Write a C function to inspect the `pg_ddl_command` structure returned by [`pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html), or
- Blindly run a `GRANT` after *every* `ALTER TABLE`, regardless of whether or not it was a `SET SCHEMA` command.

A far simpler option - provided that it fits your use case - would be to write a `move_table()` function which combines the `ALTER` and `GRANT` commands.